# PyInstaller failing to build exe -- cannot find pyproj.libs

Tags: python, pyinstaller, geopandas

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
File "geopandas\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
File "geopandas\_config.py", line 109, in <module>
File "geopandas\_config.py", line 95, in _default_use_pygeos
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
File "geopandas\_compat.py", line 9, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
File "pyproj\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
File "pyproj\__init__.py", line 39, in _delvewheel_init_patch_0_0_25
File "os.py", line 1111, in add_dll_directory
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\carrier\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI547922\\pyproj.libs'
```

I've tried adding 'pyproj.libs' to `hiddenimports` but that didn't change anything. Not sure what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `pyproj` lib directory to your data files.

For example, in your spec file:

```
a = Analysis(
    ['myscript.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=...,
    datas=[('...\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyproj.libs','pyproj.libs')],
    hiddenimports=['pyproj', ...],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=['...'],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it! I did need to change 'pygeos' to 'pyproj', if you update your answer I'll mark it as answered!

Comment: Misread, the missing lib as pygeos.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is the bundling tools (pyinstaller, cxfreeze, py2exe) aren't aware of `pyproj.libs`, because they **only** contain dynamic libraries (e.g. `.dll` files):

```bash
    Directory: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-gdal-onnx-Opor2TD1-py3.10\l 
    ib\site-packages\pyproj.libs


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        21/12/2022     20:53         619008 jpeg62-aa49b59e4c79b6d936d2f4c4d602b0f9.dll
-a----        21/12/2022     20:53         490496 libcurl-8975b871c76e7d9dda757cb5463c30f7.dll
-a----        21/12/2022     20:53         154624 liblzma-096abc6d29f3f6caa4ceeaf8481938c5.dll
-a----        21/12/2022     20:53         571312 msvcp140.dll
-a----        21/12/2022     20:53        3219968 proj-3feae4f6e6867e7b1da97fbd32eea041.dll
-a----        21/12/2022     20:53        1011200 sqlite3-ee83b4671ee10b0a425b4a0e38e79fe2.dll
-a----        21/12/2022     20:53         452096 tiff-959777470b686230774eb18d1b97235f.dll
-a----        21/12/2022     20:53          89088 zlib1-23ce3850b4e2a3bd64a2634349c2685d.dll
```

[PeaceLeka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74450941/7365866) is good for PyInstaller. For cxfreeze, use:

```py
site_packages = "C:/Users/sleet/AppData/Local/pypoetry/Cache/virtualenvs/test-gdal-onnx-Opor2TD1-py3.10/lib/site-packages"
pyproj_path = f"{site_packages}/pyproj.libs"

build_options = {
    "include_files": [(pyproj_path, "lib/pyproj.libs")]
}

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable(script = "main.py", base = "Win32GUI")]
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name= "Test pyproj",
    options = dict(build_exe=build_options),
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Test pyproj",
    executables = executables,
    # include_msvcr = True
)
```